# ECS Service other than HTTP keeps restarting

Tags: docker, containers, amazon-elb, amazon-ecs

I installed Nginx ECS Docker container service through AWS ECS, which is running without any issue. However, every other container services such as centos, ubuntu, mongodb or postgres installed through AWS ECS keeps restarting (de-registering, re-registering or in pending state) in a loop. Is there a way to install these container services using AWS ECS without any issue on AMI Optimized Linux? Also, is there a way to register Docker containers in AWS ECS that was manually pulled and ran from Docker Hub?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Usually if a container is restarting over and over again its because its not passing the health check that you setup. MongoDB for example does not use the HTTP protocol so if you set it up as a service in ECS with an HTTP healthcheck it will not be able to pass the healthcheck and will get killed off by ECS for failing to pass the healthcheck.

My recommendation would be to launch such services without using a healthcheck, either as standalone tasks, or with your own healthcheck mechanism.

If the service you are trying to run does in fact have an HTTP interface and its still not passing the healthcheck and its getting killed then you should do some debugging to verify that the instance has the right security group rules to accept traffic from the load balancer. Additionally you should verify that the ports you define in your task definition match up with the port of the healthcheck.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. I don't see any option in AWS ECS to launch a service without using a health check. I created a task definition and service for centos without using ALB but still did not work. How can I run multiple containers such as centos, mongodb, postgres, ubuntu in the same ec2 instance using AWS ECS? I tried creating separate task definitions and services for each container and mapped ports for each such as port 0 to 5002 for Centos, port 0 to 28017 for mongoDB and port 0 to 5432 for postgresql, which did not work anyway. Thanks again.

Comment: The healthcheck is part of load balancing for a service. Load balancing is optional when you create a service. You can create a service without a load balancer. Just configure it to be bound to a static port and then use your own mechanism for sending traffic to the container's port. This allows you to connect directly to a database container using its TCP protocol.

Comment: Thank you so much. I excluded all the services from health check besides of web services and it worked. I would like to know if it is possible to update AWS ECS automatically after I pull and run Docker images and container manually from using Docker CLI instead of deploying everything through ECS.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response @AlwaysALearner but you can use the Docker Compose integration for ECS to deploy to ECS or updated running containers in ECS from the Docker command line without having to go through ECS: https://docs.docker.com/cloud/ecs-integration/